# ActionBar e o SplitActionbar no Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação Android com um menu na parte superior e um na inferior. Pesquisando encontrei o `SplitActionBar` mas quando o utilizo todo a parte do `ActionBar` fica no rodapé. É possível utilizar o `ActionBar`  e o `SplitActionBar` juntos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Split action bar é uma barra separada da própria `ActionBar`. Para usa-la, você precisa implementar a ActionBar e especificar o seu uso no no `AndroidManifest.xml` da `Activity`. Exemplo:

```
<manifest ...>
    <activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

Aqui você pode ver um guia completo: [Using split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar)